# LWC Custom Label translation only working in Compact View

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforcedx, scratch-org, translation

We're facing a strange problem in Scratch Orgs where the Custom Labels used in a Lightning Web Component are not getting translated unless we switch the UI to the Compact view.

The translation for the Custom Label exists and when the view is Compact it shows correctly. But when shown in the Comfy view it falls back to the Default language. Interesting thing is that standard field labels are translated correctly in both views.

In a Sandbox this issue does not seem to be present and the correct translated label is shown in both views.

The labels are imported like this:

```
..
import missingMessage from '@salesforce/label/c.RequiredFieldsMessage';
import nameMissingMessage from '@salesforce/label/c.NamesMissingMessage';
..
 @track label = {.., missingMessage, nameMissingMessage, ..};
```

And used like this:

```
<lightning-input 
  label={labelCompRegNum} 
  maxlength="13" 
  essage-when-value-missing={label.missingMessage}
  name="compRegNr"
  placeholder={label.compRegNrPlaceholder}
  type="text">
</lightning-input>
```

Note that uiObjectInfoApi is retrieved using the uiObjectInfoApi and translates correctly.

I tried making sure that locale settings were the same as in the Sandbox too, but that should not have any effect (and didn't). 
Also thought to look though the generated html in browser dev view, but that shows the html with the "hardcoded" final value show already, of course. So I guess any difference in css classes and general structure and style can't really have an effect on the value shown.

Any ideas what may be wrong please?

[image]

UPDATE
It looks as if it's the way the labels are referenced because my colleague found a workaround (need to follow-up with him where) by adding an explicit use of any of the imported Custom Labels, even in a hidden div. With this all the labels are translated correctly all the time.

```
<div style="display:none">
  {label.compRegNrPlaceholder}
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe this is the same issue as in https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/300850/custom-labels-in-lightning-component-displayed-in-another-language/300929#300929 ?

Comment: Doesn't seem to be, I have both the default label and a custom translation explicitly set in the CustomLabels and Translation sources respectively. But there is another strange thing where if the label is used somewhere other than an attribute of the input component, suddenly all the labels seem to be fine (will update the question with more detail)